# Webpack: How to inline CSS from external file, either by link or direct path?

Tags: javascript, html-webpack-plugin

I have not had any luck trying to find a way to inline both my `JS` and `CSS` within one file, but pulling code from multiple files. Right now my work around is to place all of my `CSS` in the template file but that is a horribly slow and cumbersome way of doing it.

My current set up compiles `.ts` into a `.js` then places all of that code into my final `.html`. I want to be able to grab a `.css` file from some location and embed that into my final `.html` before the webpacking is done, so all of the code is in one file. My `inlineSource` already has `.(js|css)$` so it's supposed to inline my `CSS` source but when I use a `<link>` tag, it does not pull in the `CSS`.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/myFile/myFile.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'myFile.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/myFile')
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inlineSource: '.(js|css)$',
            filename: 'myFile.html',
            // title: 'titleHere',
            template: 'src/myFile/myFileTemplate.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(),
    ]
};
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "test/*",
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "dist/*"
    ]
}
```

I sincerely hope someone can help me because I have bashed my head over this for a while. Thanks a million in advance.